# Hide console window while running a command through c++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cmd

I used CreateProcess to run a command and used CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag but the console pops up for a small fraction of second, how to avoid it?

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

CreateProcess
( 
NULL,                // No module name (use command line)
command,             //set env variable and use it is my command
NULL,                // Process handle not inheritable
NULL,                // Thread handle not inheritable
FALSE,               // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
CREATE_NO_WINDOW,    //don't create window but it appears for fraction of second!
NULL,                // Use parent's environment block
NULL,                // Use parent's starting directory
&si,                 // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
&pi                  // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743559/how-to-execute-child-console-programs-without-showing-the-console-window-from-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redirect your output. There is a member `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` which should be redirected. [Here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an example.

Comment: could not figure it ! could tell me how exactly to do it?

Comment: Please take a look at that example. There they show exactly what your are looking for. Bascily you have to specify another device handle for `hStdOutput` and/or `hStdError`. This can be a file handle to redirect everything to a file, or a pipe handle like in the example. You can also open the NUL device `CreateFile("nul"...)` to discard the output.

Answer (score 0):

In your `STARTUPINFO` structure, set the `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag in the `dwFlags` member, and set `wShowWindow` to `SW_HIDE`.

Comment: hmm it still comes ! any idea?