# c++ run imagemagick command

Tags: c++, command, imagemagick

I want to execute the imagemagick command in background instead of displaying the window console using [ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564594/c-executing-dos-commands) or [ShellExecuteEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896778/how-to-get-return-value-of-an-exe-called-by-shellexecute), but can't get the output file.

```
ShellExecuteEx(0, _T("open"), _T("D:/convert.exe"),
               _T("convert clipboard:myimage test.png"), NULL, SW_HIDE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer. If your already writing [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) application, why not include [Magik++ library](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) into your project?

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

// ...
Magick::Image img("clipboard:myimage");
img.write("test.png");
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you wrote `ShellExecuteEx` I assume this is Windows?

See [How to execute child console programs without showing the console window from the Win32 GUI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743559/how-to-execute-child-console-programs-without-showing-the-console-window-from-th)